# Removing elements from Set in one-to-Many relationship deletes all records in my table

Tags: spring, hibernate

I have a class (Team) which a 'set' of another class (Players) making it one-to-many.  When I try clearing the set of players with my remove all function:  this.players.clear(), to add a new set, hibernate deletes both tables.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please post your code, entity, hibernate mappings, etc

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate is deleting two tables because you are clearing the set values of entity inside the transaction. Do the clearing action after closing the hibernate session.